# React Native Gorhom Bottom Sheet

Tags: react-native, modal-dialog, bottom-sheet

Hey everyone I am using React Native Gorhom Bottom Sheet and its working fine it just has one problem for me. When user opens and lowers the bottom sheet modal I want the background to change its color like when its all the way up I want the background to be dark and as it lowers I want it to be brighter.
It has a BackdropComponent and I've tried to use it but cant seem to figure it out it doesn't work for me. I just want the background color to be darker when modal is up and brighter while its going down.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try adding shadow offset?

```
shadowOffset: {
  width: ,
  height: ,
},
shadowOpacity: ,
shadowRadius: ,
```

or use `containerStyle={{backgroundColor:'red'}}` to change the color of the background.
I hope it helps you!